# ssh through a bastion machine works on someone else's desktop but not my own

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have to ssh into a bastion (jump) server in order to get to the final server.

On the jump server, my .ssh/config says:

```
Host *
 ForwardAgent yes
```

My co-worker uses PuTTy and Pageant. When I use a putty shell to connect from his desktop to the final server as root via the jump server, it works fine.

At my desk I cannot connect to the final server, only the jump server.

However, if I go to his desk, and successfully log into the final server via the jump server, I can then go back to my desk and also do so.... but after a certain amount of time, my shells revert to the original behavior of not connecting to final server via jump server.

The entire transcript of ssh -v -v -v final_server is [here](http://pastebin.com/QnKZZg2W)

The relevant part to me is when the public key is offered but then it says 'we did not send a packet':

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/CORP/t.brannon/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
```

Comment: is ForwardAgent enabled on your client, so that the needed authentication data is available on the jump host?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "client". The desired connection flow is:

my_desktop -> jump_host -> target

At any rate, because the flow works just fine once I login at my co-workers desk, I assume it must be.

But once we clear up what is meant by ForwardAgent, then I can answer you.

Comment: Do you have access to the "jump server" and is it used solely for forwarding you to the destination server?